# Calculating a total Raiden transactions' gas cost

Tags: gas, protocol

The Raiden network, which is a off-chain layer 2 implementation based on ethereum has no transaction costs,  [see link under transaction fees here](https://raiden.network/faq.html). The transaction fees are not a factor in gas cost for a raiden (layer 2) implementation- the real costs of a transaction using the raiden network is the cost of setting up the payment channel - the question is what is  the gas cost for setting up a payment channel in Raiden(any estimates or ranges for gas costs while setting up the channels)?

Answer (score 1):

With every contract version bump new gas estimations for all calls are added alongside.
For the latest version of contracts (0.10.0), gas estimations can be found here:

https://github.com/raiden-network/raiden-contracts/blob/master/raiden_contracts/data_0.10.0/gas.json

If you will have any more technical questions about Raiden, I recommend you check out official developer gitter chat as that is preferred way of communication at the moment:

https://gitter.im/raiden-network/raiden

Hope this helps! :)